# Calling all libertines

Tags: fontspec, libertine

I've prepared a package that I hope can replace all current libertine
packages (and provide partial compatibility with obsolete ones).  If you
have libertine-based documents please check it out and report problems
to me at

> rdt at cs.queensu.ca

The package can be downloaded from
ftp://linus.cs.queensu.ca/libertine.tds.zip

To install this package on a TDS-compliant TeX system unzip the file
`libertine.tds.zip` at the root of an appropriate texmf tree, likely a
personal or local tree. If necessary, update the file name database
(e.g., `texhash`). Update the font map files by enabling the map file
`libertine.map`.

For most purposes, simply add

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

to the preamble of your document.

Font encodings supported:  OT1,T1,LY1,TS1.
Engines supported: LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, xeLaTeX and luaLaTeX.

More documentation in

```
doc/fonts/libertine/README
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) While your intent is good, your message doesn't fit with the format of this site, which is about questions and answers. So this thread will most likely be closed. Please, don't take this personally: I'd very happy if your project reveals successful, thus ending months of uncertainty about what to do in order to typeset with the Libertine fonts. We all wait for your contributions to this site.

Comment: If you manage to get 20 reputation you can join us in the [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) chat room. You might also want to complete your profile.

Comment: Nice package. Why don't you upload it in CTAN?

Comment: It *is* in CTAN indeed! Why post it here, then?

Comment: @NVaughan Where? I could only find [Herbert Voß' Type-1 variant](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine). @user22108 The [`iftex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) package provides `\ifPDFTeX` (and also `\ifXeTeX` and `\ifLuaTeX`).